# Removing existing Where clauses

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I want to remove where clauses in some conditions:

```php
$q = Thread::with('comments')->take(10);

if(strlen($input) < 4){
   $result = $q->where('title', '~', "^$input$")->get();

   if($result->isNotEmpty()){
       return $result;
   }

   // if was empty:
}

// How to clean the where clause from the above here? because it affect the query below:

$result = $q->where('title', 'like', "%$input%")->get();
```

The problem is the first where clause affects the second one if the data was empty, How can i remove existing where clauses when needed ? also the `newQuery()` is not working in my case.

Note that i'm using two seperate statement in postgres `~` and 'like'

Something like [reorder()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#removing-existing-orderings) for where clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do it

```
$q = Thread::with('comments')->take(10);

if(strlen($input) < 4){
   $result = $q->where('title', '~', "^$input$")->get();
   if($result->isNotEmpty()){
     return $results;
   }
 }
```

// **getQuery()** is a query builder method that contains all the groupings, selects, orders, wheres, joins etc for the query that you are accessing or trying to build.

```
$q->getQuery()->wheres= [];
$result = $q->where('title', 'like', "%$input%")->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Conditional Clauses**

```
$threads = Thread::with('comments')->when(strlen($input) < 4, function ($query) use ($input) {
    return $query->where('title', '~', "^$input$");
}, function ($query) use ($input) {
    return $query->where('title', 'like', "%$input%");
})->take(10)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

If you want to give it a second change I would write that logic like this. Comments are loaded only if they are needed.

```
if (strlen($input) < 4) {
   $threads = Thread::where('title', '~', "^$input$")->take(10)->get();

   if ($threads->isNotEmpty()) {
       return $threads->load('comments');
   }
}

return Thread::with('comments')->where('title', 'like', "%$input%")->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: What happens if the first condition was empty ? look at my code it gave second chance if it was empty

Comment: If you want to gave a second chance, then start query from the beginning again.

Comment: Yes i'm looking for this spot, how to not duplicate this...

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

if you cloning before add where
it works the same as deleting where

```
...
if(strlen($input) < 4){
   $result = (clone $q)->where('title', '~', "^$input$")->get();

   if($result->isNotEmpty()){
       return $results;
   }

}

$result = $q->where('title', 'like', "%$input%")->get();
...
```

Comment: I like this approach more than other answers.